# Unsecure Prompt in IIS

Tags: iis

In IIS server 10,i assign a ssl to my site and run it and everything is good and certificate work correctly but in my network( all of IP such as IIS server and clients are same IP); but when I'm testing the site from local client prompt me " unsecure connection"
What can i do?

Problem in IIS Server 10

Comment: You need to run a diagnostics report and edit the question to include it. Otherwise, we cannot guess how you configured the site, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 1):

The browser warns of this error, which only contains CN (Common Name) but no corresponding SAN (Service Alternative Name). so you have to set the hostname in iis with the corresponding common name or buy the certificate as the name as a hostname

Comment: The browser can complain that for a lot of reasons. Too early to recommend such.